# How to save the name of dropdownlist instead of its ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I m been working on a project in which i m facing an issue 
I m having two drop down list which are Select category (ddlcategory) and select subcategory (ddlsubcategory) here are they
[image: Image of the drop down list]

When I'm saving the data i m getting the ID saved into my database instead of category name and subcategory name Here is my database values :
[image: Image of stored values that is Id of which i want to store the name]
Here is my back code i have implemented :

```
 String constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
string query = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindCategoryDropdown();
    }
}
protected void btnpreviewwebsite_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:50550/Online Tours and Travels/index.aspx");
}
protected void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:50550/Online Tours and Travels/Admin Panel/LoginForm.aspx");

}
protected void BindCategoryDropdown()
{
    //conenction path for database
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from category", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlcategory.DataSource = ds;
    ddlcategory.DataTextField = "Cat_name";
    ddlcategory.DataValueField = "Cat_id";
    ddlcategory.DataBind();
    ddlcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    ddlsubcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}

protected void ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int categoryid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlcategory.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from subcategory where catid=" + categoryid, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlsubcategory.DataSource = ds;
    ddlsubcategory.DataTextField = "subcatname";
    ddlsubcategory.DataValueField = "subcatid";
    ddlsubcategory.DataBind();
    ddlsubcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

}
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    String pathName1 = "~/packageimages/" + Path.GetFileName(fileuploadpic1.PostedFile.FileName);
    String pathName2 = "~/packageimages/" + Path.GetFileName(fileuploadpic2.PostedFile.FileName);
    String pathName3 = "~/packageimages/" + Path.GetFileName(fileuploadpic3.PostedFile.FileName);
    query = 
    "insert into package(packname,catid,categoryname,subcatname,packageprice,pic1,pic2,pic3,detail) values('"+txtpackagename.Text+"','"+txtcategoryid.Text+"','"+ddlcategory.Text+"','"+ddlsubcategory.Text+"','"+txtpackageprice.Text+"','"+pathName1+"','"+pathName2+"','"+pathName3+"','"+txtdetails.Text+"') ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    fileuploadpic1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/packageimages/" + fileuploadpic1.FileName));
    fileuploadpic2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/packageimages/" + fileuploadpic2.FileName));
    fileuploadpic2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/packageimages/" + fileuploadpic3.FileName));
    txtpackagename.Text = "";
    txtcategoryid.Text = "";
    txtpackageprice.Text = "";
    txtdetails.Text = "";
    string message = "Package Added !!";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
    sb.Append("alert('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("')};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
}
```

Please do help ! Thank You

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is a textbook example of sql injection vulnerability. As for the question at hand, why would you want to save the name? If your structure is properly normalized you should have the ID in the package table, not the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering your question - you need to use

`ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text` not `ddlcategory.Text`

But as suggested, first do learn about query parameters
for example [here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)
And about `using` statement for example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)

Comment: Thank you so much brother it helped for me thanx alot :) @Jury Golubev

Answer (score 1):

The name of a Control gets generated by aspnet itself. Depending where in the control tree a Control is located, it could become something like this:

```
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$TextBox1
```

But if you really want to get the name, you can use `UniqueID`.

```
string controlName = TextBox1.UniqueID;
```